# What's the normal procedure for finding the name of the necessary ESLint package based on the config name given in the error message?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I was just struggling with the error below in my IDE for a frustratingly-long time:

`ESLint: Error: Failed to load config "@vue/typescript" to extend from.`

After a lot of Googling and running commands I found online, I eventually found that what (seemed to) fix the problem was running this:

`yarn add -D @vue/eslint-config-typescript`

My question is: How was I supposed to figure that out?  Is there some website or service or something where I could have searched for `@vue/typescript` and found out that the package I needed to install was `@vue/eslint-config-typescript`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out: [in the ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/plugins#include-a-plugin), it says that basically that the part after the forward-slash should be understood to always start with `eslint-plugin`:

They show the following examples:

```
"plugins": [
    "jquery", // means eslint-plugin-jquery
    "@jquery/jquery", // means @jquery/eslint-plugin-jquery
    "@foobar" // means @foobar/eslint-plugin
]
```